# Create new column indicator for the latest date within each group

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a dataset that looks like this. 
I want to create new column that is an indicator to show if the date for the group is the Latest.

I attached a sample data below:

```
Item    Group   Date
item1   a   1/1/2019
item2   a   2/1/2019
item3   a   3/1/2019
item6   b   1/1/2019
item7   b   2/1/2019
item8   b   2/1/2019
item9   b   3/1/2019
```

For each group (a or b), I want to create an indicator that shows if the Date is the Latest within its group. 
I attached a sample of what I want to accomplish:

```
Item    Group   Date    Indicator
item1   a   1/1/2019    
item2   a   2/1/2019    
item3   a   3/1/2019    Latest
item6   b   1/1/2019    
item7   b   2/1/2019    
item8   b   3/1/2019    
item9   b   4/1/2019    Latest
```

This is my code so far. It is able to find the latest date but it does not seem to separate by Group.

```
data$Indicator <- ifelse(data$Date == max(data$Date) & data$Group == "a", "Latest",
                           ifelse(data$Date == max(data$Date) & data$Group == "b", "Latest",""))
```

I realize the `data$Date == max(data$Date)` statement does not distinguish between the Groups, so I tried using `mutate` but it seems I am setting it up wrong.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(Indicator = ifelse(data$Date == max(data$Date), "Latest",""))
```

Wondering if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the date to date class we can compare date with `max` date value in each `Group` and use `ifelse` to assign `Indicator`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
 group_by(Group) %>%
 mutate(Indicator = ifelse(Date == max(Date), 'Latest', ''))

# Item  Group Date       Indicator
#  <chr> <chr> <date>     <chr>    
#1 item1 a     2019-01-01 ""       
#2 item2 a     2019-02-01 ""       
#3 item3 a     2019-03-01 "Latest" 
#4 item6 b     2019-01-01 ""       
#5 item7 b     2019-02-01 ""       
#6 item8 b     2019-02-01 ""       
#7 item9 b     2019-03-01 "Latest"
```

---

Another approach could be to `arrange` the data and assign `"Latest"` `Indicator` on last line in each group.

```
df %>%
 mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
 arrange(Group, Date) %>%
 group_by(Group) %>%
 mutate(Indicator = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 'Latest', ''))
```

Comment: Thank you! 
The first snippet you sent worked fine. I am curious though, because the mutate function you wrote seems identical to the one I wrote except I used data$Date while you just wrote Date.
I didnt catch it when I was creating the sample data but in my original dataset the Date column is in the Date format you suggested above. Apart from that, the code looks identical except for how I called the Date column in my code. Do you know why R treats this differently? Thank you again!

Comment: If you check `class(df$Date)` in your post it might be either "character" or "factor", that is not a valid type to compare dates. Hence, this line `mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y'))` is really important to change into date format. Moreover, you should never use `$` in `dplyr` pipe when you do that it doesn't respect the grouping and takes data from entire dataframe.